# Regular expression in grepWin to match three specified words separated by anything in a text block

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm using a grepWin windows tool and I would like to find anything that could contains "start transaction" then a space or any character then "st_message_index"
then commit;

It should match something like this:

```
enter code heredeclare continue handler;
start transaction;

select  n.id as messageIndexId

from    st_message_index

commit;

end main $$`
```

and do not match something like this

```
declare continue handler;
start transaction;

select  n.id as messageIndexId

   from employee

commit;

end main $$
```

None of this works:

```
transaction[\w\s]+audittrail[\w\s]+commit

start transaction;.*[\w\s]+st_message_index.*[\w\s]+commit

.*[\w\s]+.*start transaction;.*[\w\s]+.*st_message_index.*[\w\s]+.*commit;.*[\w\s]+.*
```

If there is any solution using regular expressions in a mysql query finding procedures definitions that will also work for me and solve my problem.

Something like

```
    select name
    FROM mysql.proc
    WHERE body regexp 'transaction[\w\s]+audittrail[\w\s]+commit';
```

Comment: It could contains anything (characters or spaces) between the three keywords (start transaction, st_message_index and commit

Comment: I just added three examples not working.

Comment: You've got the right idea. Try turning on "single-line" mode in whatever language you're using, so that `.` can match a newline character. (You need this in order to match text that spans multiple lines.) https://regex101.com is a good site to use for playing with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

This regexp will give me what i want. Thanks @asherber for the link to the regex101.com website

```
start transaction[\w\s=;\(\),.*]*audittrail[\w\s=;\(\),.*]*commit
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[:<:]]start transaction[[:>:]].*[[:<:]]audittrail[[:>:]].*[[:<:]]commit[[:>:]]
```

This assumes that the regexp you are using has `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` for "word boundary".